# SQL statement GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do the best seller system but I am having some problem on the SQL statement. Here is my SQL:

```
select sp.name, pr.productName, op.productID, SUM(op.orderQuantity) AS totalQty from sm_orderedproduct op
INNER JOIN sm_payment p ON op.orderID = p.orderID 
INNER JOIN sm_product pr ON op.productID = pr.productID
INNER JOIN sm_sellerproduct sp ON sp.productID = pr.productID
WHERE MONTH(str_to_date( dateOfPurchase, '%d/%m/%Y' )) = 7
GROUP BY sp.name, pr.productName, op.productID
ORDER BY SUM(op.orderQuantity) DESC LIMIT 4;
```

With this SQL statement, I get duplicate seller name. For example

> Seller Dean sold 97 TV
>
> Seller Rk sold 20 Desktop
>
> Seller Dean again sold 15 harddisks
>
> Seller Gab sold 2 wooden tables

As you can see, seller Dean is repeated twice because of different products sold. I want to do like:

> Seller Dean sold 112 products
>
> Seller Rk sold 20 products
>
> Seller Gab sold 2 products
>
> And whatever seller sold ? products

I believe that there's something went wrong with my group by clause. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry? what you mean by postgres

Comment: @Gwen -- Postgres is a database.  Gaston was asking which db are you using.  Looks like MySQL...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the product related information from the query/group by:

```
select sp.name, sum(op.orderQuantity) AS totalQty 
from sm_orderedproduct op
    inner join sm_payment p ON op.orderID = p.orderID 
    inner join sm_product pr ON op.productID = pr.productID
    inner join sm_sellerproduct sp ON sp.productID = pr.productID
where MONTH(str_to_date( dateOfPurchase, '%d/%m/%Y' )) = 7
group by sp.name
order by sum(op.orderQuantity) desc 
limit 4;
```

Comment: @Gwen -- np, glad I could help!